# How do I trace the usage of functions and variables through a C++/Javascript project

Tags: javascript, c++, trace

I'm looking to map out the usage of Javascript in the 0 A.D. project, such as the flow of operations when the mouse is clicked. I have found functions that define parts of the process, but the points where the functions are called are in different files. I'm looking for some program that will walk through all the files, find those references, and tell me which file calls what and defines what. It cannot operate through the web browser because this Javascript is not designed to work with a web browser, but with a game engine written in C++... so unless there is a way to implement the trace in the game's engine, some sort of file-walking tool would be best. I think this is called a static-trace?
Sorta what I'm looking for: 
funcA() - fileA.js
  fileB.js - Line 144
  fileC.js - Line 12

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think doxygen can create call graphs. Beware: Creating a call graph might take quite some time.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse IDE can do this for C++ (eclipse CDT version).

Select your function, then in the menu bar click "Navigate" -> "Open call hierarchy..."

You can then select "callers" or "callees".

There is an eclipse version for javascript, maybe it can do it, too.